# reference the table of contents/ hyperlink

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, lists

when i use the \tableofcontents or \listoffigures, it creates a page with the hyperlink placed on the name of the section.There  is a red square around the title. However i want the hyperlink to be on the page numbers on the right after the dots instead of on the text of the section name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `linktocpage` helps:

```
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}
```

As alternative the new option `linktoc` can be used:

```
linktoc=page
```

This option allows further settings link making both parts to links:

```
linktoc=all
```

See [README](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf) for a description of `linktoc`.